# rsync error: exit code 23 ( No such file or directory (2) )

Tags: windows, cygwin, rsync

Rsync reports error for one file (other files were copied just fine):

rsync: stat "//serverName/destination/.lpt$vpn.251.yiOK8j" failed: No such file or directory (2)

rsync: rename "//serverName/destination/.lpt$vpn.251.yiOK8j" -> ".lpt$vpn.251": No such file or directory (2)

File ".lpt$vpn.251.yiOK8j" does exist in "//serverName/destination/"

Rsync parameters:

rsync.exe -rltDvP -W --delete --progress "/cygdrive/C/source/Downloads/Unpacked/" "//serverName/destination" --exclude "OK.marker" --modify-window=2'

Seems like a dollar sign or double dot in file name causing that, so my question is how to guarantee rsync could copy any windows file no matter what its name is?

Cygwin version is 1.7.9

Rsync version is 3.0.9

Answer (score 0):

Dollar signs are a way that bash outputs a parameter (variable)  value.

The dot just hides the file from a normal ls.

Is the file really there ? $vpn could mean anything. Escaping the $ is not typical, so I'm wondering why someone would make a file with that name, or if that string has variables in it.

This is a question for someone with more bash experience than me, but I thought I'd throw my 2 cents in.

Comment: File is there, I know name looks strange, it's Trend Micro Sysclean definitions, if for example you download archive from http://officescan-p.activeupdate.trendmicro.com/activeupdate/pattern/vsapi.zip

it contains file in the format "lpt$vpn.{version}", e.g. lpt$vpn.255

So in this particlar case it's a dollar sign, but there could be other special characters that rsync threats in a special way, so I want to make sure it could handle file with any name that Windows might have.